# Javascript or lodash nested JSON object transformation

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

How to make nested object null

if object attributes has a null values. please check the JSON below

I have JSON data as following

```
[{
    "student": {
        "id": null,
        "name": null
    },
    "children": [{
        "student": null,
        "children": [{
                "student": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "A"
                }
            },
            {
                "student": {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

I want to convert it to following output

`Expected`

```
[{
    "student": null,
    "children": [{
        "student": null,
        "children": [{
                "student": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "A"
                }
            },
            {
                "student": null
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "nullify" values if their values are all null using the following conditional.

```js
Object.values(obj).every(value => value == null)
```

I created a basic recursive function to below that traverses the object and checks to see if it needs to nullify an object. This is all done in-place, and it will modify the original object.

```js
const obj = [{
  "student": { "id": null, "name": null },
  "children": [{
    "student": null,
    "children": [
      { "student": { "id": 1, "name": "A" } },
      { "student": { "id": null, "name": null } }
    ]
  }]
}];

const nullify = (obj, key = null, parent = null) => {
  if (obj != null) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      obj.forEach((item, index) => nullify(item, index, obj));
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
      if (Object.values(obj).every(value => value == null)) {
        parent[key] = null;
      } else {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => nullify(value, key, obj));
      }
    }
  }
};

nullify(obj);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ student: { id: null, name: null }, children: [{ student: null, children: [{ student: { id: 1, name: 'A' } }, { student: { id: null, name: null } }] }] }];

const nullify = objectScan(['**(^children$).student'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value }) => {
    if (
      value instanceof Object
      && !Array.isArray(value)
      && Object.values(value).every((e) => e === null)
    ) {
      parent[property] = null;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(nullify(data));
// => 2

console.log(data);
// => [ { student: null, children: [ { student: null, children: [ { student: { id: 1, name: 'A' } }, { student: null } ] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)